# how to stop timers when leaving a "screen"

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some timers running on a page that I am having trouble figuring out how to stop when I navigate away from that page, while the page is running.

The call is coming from a button on another movie clip, which is invoking a function on Main.as. The

function in Main.as does this:

```
public function goToIntro(){

            removeChild(currentScreen); 
            intro = new Intro();
            addChildAt(intro,0);
            currentScreen = intro;



        }
```

I get this error message if I click the Intro button while any scene with timers is playing. The message

doesn't come up right away, it appears just as the Intro "scene" is ending and calling the next scene.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.  
    at MethodInfo-202()  
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()  
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

I have this code on the Intro page, that is supposed to handle cleaning it up when it is removed.

```
public function Intro() {

            addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, removedHandler);


private function removedHandler(event:Event):void {



}
```

I cannot figure out how to kill the timers from the removedHander function. I tried removing the event listeners but that causes other error messages. I tried doing a test if the listener is not null, then stopping it. That apparently never runs (I used trace statements to test it). I tried testing if the timer was .running and then stopping it, but that didnt work either.

Help!

Also, I am a complete newbie to actionscript and programming so it's ok to talk to me like I was a 5 year old. Thanks

Comment: inside your currentScreen class add and event listener for "removedFromStage" and stop the timer in the handler.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop a `Timer` using the [`Timer.stop()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html#stop%28%29) call. You can make this call in your `removedHandler`, like so:

```
private function removedHandler(event:Event):void {
    if (myTimer != null) myTimer.stop();
}
```

This means that you must keep a reference to your timer around in order to stop it. In this case, the reference is `myTimer`.

Comment: I did pretty much exactly that, and according to my tracers, that new code never ran. And I still got the same error message.

Comment: So you are saying that `removedHandler` is never called? Is `Intro` the MovieClip that is being removed? Your question makes it sound like the problem happens when you go into the intro, not when you exit it. Instead of listening for `REMOVED_FROM_STAGE`, you could also stop the timer directly in your `goToIntro` function.

Comment: removedHandler is running, but the If myTimer !=null bits apparently never run. I look into the goToIntro idea, thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! If `myTimer != null` isn't running, that's because `myTimer` is not set in the current scope. Make sure you set `myTimer` in the appropriate place when you create your timer: `myTimer = new Timer(10, foo);`